# cocoa - How to resize one direction

Tags: macos, cocoa, resize

I want to resize the window just one direction like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGf2S.png) when mouse moves at bottom right corner.

The window will resize when user move following this direction.

If user pull following vertical/horizontal, the window will not resize.

Have any ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might want to just set your window's `contentAspectRatio`.

In case you need more control than that, here's an excerpt from the [*Window Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SizingPlacingWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000228-135785):

> Additionally, when a window is about to be resized, the window’s delegate will be sent a `windowWillResize:toSize:` message. You can implement that method in your delegate to easily control your window’s size.